# While in Swift playground I accidentally hit some Key and now cannot type... stuck with "?" symbol insead of curser

Tags: swift-playground

This is a real nube question, sorry guys but this is real frustrating.
Tried quitting Xcode, and deleting the old playground but the "?" is still there and will not let me type!

Comment: Never had this, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a month down the tack, and having repeated the error a several times I have finally figured out the issue.
Background:
My set up is a Win10 machine with a remote Mac server (MacinCloud)
The Issue:
When typing and deleting, I occasionally would miss and hit the "Insert" key. This would render any further editing impossible. The solution at this stage is to log off the remote server and log back in.

Final solution... cover the "Insert" key with a 3-sided cardboard bracket. :)